# EUnhandled Exception: PlatformException(87, null, null, null) when i debug on windows browse then this error generate in network info plus

Tags: flutter

ERROR:flutter/runtime/dart_vm_initializer.cc(41)] Unhandled Exception: PlatformException(87, null, null, null) when i debug on windows browse then this error generate in network info plus

i try flutter clean then flutter pub get

Answer (score 0):

Network Info Plus is not supported on Web, written in the first line:

***The functionality is not supported on Web.***

https://pub.dev/packages/network_info_plus